# How to delete realm objects with their child relations?

Tags: android, realm

I have a big object that has a lot of relationships with other objects and those objects have relationships with other objects as well. So when i delete the root object, i found out that only the parent object is being deleted while all its relationships are not, is there way to delete the whole tree in the same transaction ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Realm doesn't support `cascading delete` for now. You can vote for that feature [there](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1104). In the current case, seems you need to do it manually, one by one.

```
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        RootObj root = realm.where(RootObj.class)
                            .equalTo(RootObjFields.ID, rootId)
                            .findFirst();
        if(root != null) {
            if(root.getChild() != null) {
               root.getChild().deleteFromRealm();
            }
            root.deleteFromRealm();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: how did you generate RootObjFields

Comment: Worth to mention about many-to-x relationships. If another object uses the same dependency, the code above will get rid of the dependency, and the second object will have invalidated dependency, what may lead to crash. Eg. for model `User { Address }` we create `address1 = Address()` and `user1=User(address1); user2=User(address1)`. Then deleting address1 by deleting user1 will cause user2 not to have the address relationship properly set.