# Deleting multiple objects from a local Realm Database on iOS

Tags: swift, realm

I am finishing up an app utilizing a local Realm database with three models. When I delete an object from the main master model, the connected objects in the child models are supposed to all delete, but only one of the objects in each model deletes. See the attache diagram.

Not sure where to go next. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Blessings,
—Mark

[image: diagram of problem]

Comment: Please add appropriate tags to questions. If you're using swift, add it (I did that for you). Also, it's important that questions  are clear; using words like *connected objects* is vague. How are they connected? Are they stored in a Collection like a List? If so, those are references to other objects and they are not supposed to delete. Most importantly, **include your code** as this is a programming site and a couple of lines of code can speak a thousands words. Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

This is the normal behavior of realm js.
When you delete one element of the master model, the child element related is still present on the database.

The only solution is to get all child element and delete them first.
For example if you have a Master model named "Order" and a child model named "customer" :

```
/** if you use realm-js **/

const order = realm.objects('Order').filtered(`id = 1`)[0]
realm.write(() => {
  realm.delete(order.customer)
  realm.delete(order)
})
```

also you can find related related post with the same question
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37610919/deleting-children-on-deleting-parent-on-realm) or
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40426414/how-to-delete-realm-objects-with-their-child-relations)

Comment: Thanks so much, this is helpful. I am using Swift, but I get the idea.  Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 1):

Anyone else with this question, knowing the child databases must be deleted first, the solution became self-evident. Thanks again for pointing this out!.

```
//get the object at indexPath.row
           let a = self.master![indexPath.row]
           let id = a.Id //master's record ID
           let n = realm.objects(Child1.self).filter("Id = %@", id)
           let r = realm.objects(Child2.self).filter("Id = %@", id)

           //Delete object at indexPath.row
           try! realm.write {
               realm.delete(n)
               realm.delete(r)
               //delete last
               realm.delete(a)
           }
```

Blessings,
—Mark

Comment: This solution doesn't make sense in the context its written. `let id = a.Id` get's the master record ID and then you are filtering child object **Id** for the master records id? The child objects Id will be it's own Id, not the master records Id. Perhaps the child objects don't have their own Id? If you can clarify how this answers the question, we can upvote it so it can help others.

Comment: Sure. The Master Id is the source of truth. The child databases need to filter their records that match the Master ID so only the records associated with the individual Master ID's object are deleted, leaving the other objects in the Master and the objects in the associated records of the two-child databases untouched. The master ID is saved in the child database objects when they are created so it knows which Master Object belong to it.

Comment: This is the delete function of the Garage Record App I created. The Master holds the individual vehicles in the database and one child database contains that individual service records for a specific vehicle and the other child database contain the notes regarding the service of said specific vehicle. I hope that clears up what I  am doing and if helpful for someone else.

Comment: So your child objects have a property `ID` but it's actually the master objects ID? If so, you may want to use an inverse relationship instead or name the property something that's a bit more clear like 'master_id' or 'parent_id'. Typically if it's just named 'Id' it's assumed it's the Id of that object.